# C assign some values of one struct to another

Tags: c

I am having a problem with my code. I am attempting to get some of the values from one of my structs to assign to another. Everything I find on here is about assigning the whole struct to the other. 
What I am after is a drone is selected from an array of 10 drones and the details in the struct is assigned to a new member of the delivery_info struct so it can be formatted on the screen in a table.

Currently is not assigning the values from the drone struct to the delivery as intended

I have attached what I have at the moment.

```
void drone_delivery(Delivery *delivery_info, Drone *drones, float x1, float x2, float y1, float y2, int total, float item_weight, int*totalD){


        totalD = realloc(totalD, sizeof(delivery_info) * (*totalD+1));
        float cDistance = sqrt((pow(x2-x1,2) ) + (pow(y2-y1,2)));
        printf("%4.2f\n", cDistance);
        int i;

            for ( i = 0; i < total; i++)
                if (drones[i].maxDist >= cDistance && drones[i].loadCapacity >= item_weight) {

                    delivery_info[i].droneNumber = drones[i].droneNumber;
                    strcpy(drones[i].droneName, delivery_info[i].droneName);
                    delivery_info[i].maxDist = drones[i].maxDist;
                    delivery_info[i].loadCapacity = drones[i].loadCapacity;
                    delivery_info[i].x1=x1;
                    delivery_info[i].y1=y1;
                    delivery_info[i].x2= x2;
                    delivery_info[i].y2 = y2;

                }
        print_delivery_info(delivery_info[i]);
        *totalD+=1;
}
```

Comment: What is the problem? What is `totalD` for that you reallocate and then increment what it points to?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [the help pages](http://stackoverflow.com/help), take the SO [tour], read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/).

Comment: what is the problem?

Comment: What is it doing?  What do you want it to do?  You have not described a problem.

Comment: Hi Sorry, I need it to search an array of drone structs and after it selects one based on the input weight and distance i need it to assign the values from the drone struct to the delivery info struct to print.

Comment: Three possible problems: 1) The pointer `delivery_info` is invalid; 2) The array pointed to by `delivery_info` doesn't have enough memory allocated for it and you write out of bounds; 3) The copying: You copy from `drones[i]` to `delivery_info[i]`, but what if there are some `drone` elements you don't copy? Then the index `i` will still be increased and you skip elements in `delivery_info` leaving holes in that array. You need to use two separate indexes for `drones` and `delivery_info` respectively.

Comment: Then a definite problem: After the copying loop ends, `i` will be equal to `total` which is out of bounds of the `drones` array, and if it's in-bounds for `delivery_info` then `delivery_info[i]` will be an uninitialized elements in the `delivery_info` array. The last *possibly* initialized element of `delivery_info` *might* be `i - 1`.

Comment: Some [rubber duck debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) (and a room- or class-mate) would be of good help finding such problems.

Comment: Thanks for that :) definitely would be nice if i could bounce off some class mates.